# How do I search from newest first in mutt?

Tags: mutt

When I perform a search in mutt it searches from oldest to newest. How do I reverse this?

I have tried to read the documentation for searching in mutt [here](https://legacy.gl.ciw.edu/static/users/rcohen/mutt/manual-6.html), but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `search-reverse`; the default key command is `<Esc>/` instead of just `/` for `search`. Alternatively you can use `O` to reverse the mailbox sort (`sort-reverse`).